# Can I use same external drive to backup and install new version?

Tags: boot, system-installation, external-hdd, format, drive

I have an old laptop with sadly out of date 10.04 Lucid on it.  The internal drive is partitioned and contains Windows 7, which I never use.  Gradually, it's losing functionality, as more software becomes incompatible with it.

I recently bought an external drive to backup all my data on.  My plan is to reformat the internal drive on the laptop and *start over* with the current LTS version (14.04 Trusty), simplifying the partition tree in the process by wiping away Windows, etc.

**Question:**  Can I also use the external drive to boot from and to reinstall the Ubuntu?  Perhaps on a separate partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is a clear "NO".

You should **never ever use the same external drive for data-backup and as booting-device.**

For this purpose, i really recommend, to use two different media.

For data-backup, I would recommend, that you use your existing external harddrive.
As boot-device, you can either use a fresh and clean DVD (which you burnt the iso-image on) or otherwise - as I do it - a usb-stick. For this purpose, a usb-stick with 8GB space is just enough.

So prepare this usb-stick as your boot-media.

For this purpose, the safest way is, to your unetBootin. I always use that and it took me to clean installations.

Greetings
Andrea